# Make a custom CLI

Tags: magento2

I have this Command .php file inside Test/Coba/Command/SetCron.php

```
<?php
namespace Icube\Coba\Console;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Test\Coba\Controller\Index\Index;
use Test\Coba\Controller\Index\Save;

class SaveCron extends Command
{
    protected $deleteItem;
    protected $saveItem;
    protected $helper;

    public function __construct(
        Index $deleteItem,
        Save $saveItem,
        \Test\Coba\Helper\Data $helper
    ){
        $this->deleteItem = $deleteItem;
        $this->saveItem = $saveItem;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('save:category');
        $this->setDescription('Demo command line');
        
        parent::configure();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input,OutputInterface $output){
        $this->deleteItem->execute();
        $this->saveItem->execute();
        $output->writeln("Hello World Theree!");
    }
}
```

and my crontab.xml inside Test/etc/crontab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">   
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="autocategory_cli" xsi:type="object">Test\Coba\Console\SaveCron</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

i did set:di:compile and cache:flush but unfortunately my CLI wont registered in the system and give this error message, anyone know what mistakes that i did?

[image]

edit:

Index.php
<?php

```
namespace Test\Coba\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryLinkRepository;
use \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $productCollectionFactory;
    protected $_categoryLinkManagement;
    protected $_categoryLinkRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $pageFactory,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,      
        CategoryLinkRepository $_categoryLinkRepository,
        CategoryLinkManagementInterface $_categoryLinkManagement
    ) {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_categoryLinkRepository = $_categoryLinkRepository;
        $this->_categoryLinkManagement = $_categoryLinkManagement;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    private function DeleteProductFromCategory()
    {
        $categoryId = 41;
        $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $categoryId]);

        foreach ($productCollection as $product){
            $this->_categoryLinkRepository->deleteByIds($categoryId, $product->getSku());
            echo $product->getSku() . "has been deleted";
        }
    }

    public function execute() 
    {
        $this->DeleteProductFromCategory();
    }
}
```

Save.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Coba\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface;

class Save extends Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    protected $productCollectionFactory;
    protected $_categoryLinkManagement;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $pageFactory,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        CategoryLinkManagementInterface $_categoryLinkManagement
    ) {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_categoryLinkManagement = $_categoryLinkManagement;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
    
    private function CreatedAt()
    {
        $date = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('category_setting/general/day',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        $month = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('category_setting/general/month',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        $year = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('category_setting/general/year',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        return  $year .'-' .$month .'-' .$date . ' 00:00:00';
    }

    private function AddNewProductToCategory()
    {
        $categoryId = array('41');
        $productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' =>$this->CreatedAt()]);

        foreach ($productCollection as $product){ 
            if($product->getData('Exclude_From_New') == 0) {
                $this->_categoryLinkManagement->assignProductToCategories($product->getSku(), $categoryId);
                echo $product->getName(). 'added';
            }
        }
    }

    public function execute() 
    {
        $this->AddNewProductToCategory();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think configuration must be defined inside the `di.xml` not in crontab

Comment: i moved the config to my di.xml, but after i setup:upgrade, new errors occured `Area code is not set`. do you know what this errors refers to? Thanks in advance @SiarheyUchukhlebau

Answer (score 0):

Please add this in your frontend/di.xml or adminhtml/di.xml based on the use case

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Icube\Coba\Console\SaveCron">
      <arguments>
         <!-- configure the command name via constructor $name argument -->
         <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">save:category</argument>
      </arguments>
   </type>
</config>
```

Then update the di.xml with commandListInterface

Please follow this Magento doc for the right way to create cli commands
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/cli-cmds/cli-howto.html

if the state is required please update your code like this
there are many states in Magento:
admin
adminhtml
catalog
crontab
doc
frontend
global
setup

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\State **/
private $state;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\State $state) {
    $this->state = $state;
    parent::__construct();
}

public function execute() {
    $this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND); // or \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML, depending on your needs
}
```

Note:
Crontab.xml magento guide
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-tut.html

Comment: i already moved to `di.xml` but right now an error `Area code is not set` occured.

Comment: use Test\Coba\Controller\Index\Index;
use Test\Coba\Controller\Index\Save;
I need to see the above two files 
There might be a code that requires area code to be set

I hope there is some frontend context been used 
That is why it requires area code

Comment: Just remove Index and Save classes in Import, Constructor, 
then the command will work

you need to write the code inside this execute method instead using Controller

Comment: i already updated my thread with my codes, please kindly to check.

Comment: yes, you updated the namespace did you tried by removing those two controllers?